# protected void RadFileExplorer1_ItemCommand(object sender, RadFileExplorerEventArgs e) not fired

Tags: telerik, radfileexplorer

"protected void RadFileExplorer1_ItemCommand(object sender, RadFileExplorerEventArgs e)" not firing with file upload

Comment: It did for me. Make sure the files pass validation and there are no issues with the upload (e.g., no bad file names, the file does not exceed the limit set in the web.config, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

this event only fire while customizing the radfile explorer. and to do that we need add a user control and find the radfile explorer control then bind and fire the event.